# How to remove blank lines in Crystal Report in c# Windows application

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to make an accounting ledger details in Crystal Report. But, I need to remove some blank lines as marked in the screenshot. I tried Suppressing blank lines, but it doesn't remove it. Please help me on how to remove these blank lines: [image]

[image]

Comment: Sharing some more details about your report query or code behind will help it resolve better.

Comment: This report is ledger party statement both side credit and debit amount with credit, debit details. for ex. credit entry details text wrap than not effect to dr and drDetails. it not blank row print but it remove blank row.

Comment: try to suppress or drag your crystal report up until it reach below the text of your crystal report

Comment: please give me example how to suppress or drag crystal report up until it reach below

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put this formula at the suppress formula editor

if isnull({FieldName} ) then 
true 
else
false

Comment: i have left side cr , crRefDate, crDetail  and right side dr,drRefDate,drDetail, there are 6 filed in details section i also try to if isnull({crDetails}) and isnull({drDetails}) but it also blank space.

Comment: can it print every column independent print in crystal report?

Comment: please try this option, dont put the formula at the section expert of the detail section. but try to right click on the object-->format object. you can see another suppress option there.

Comment: i can not under stand what you are saying. i try to create this report some day but not any result.

Comment: please give me example i can under stand and solve this problem.

Comment: please give me any example as above question.